# Flask + html - sending data to template being extended

Tags: html, flask

I have a fairly simple setup. I created a flask app and call index.html on route '/'.

index.html contains this:

```
{% extends "template.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <h4 class="centeredText">
        HEADER TEXT
    </h4>

    {% for p in paragraph %}
        <p class="centeredText">
            {{ p }}
        </p>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

My template.html is also very simple:

```
<html>

    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href = "{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href = "{{ url_for('static', filename='custom.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href = "{{ url_for('static', filename='custom_navbar.css') }}">    
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <head>
        <h1>{% if pageType = 'home' %} HOME {% endif %}</h1>
    </head>

    <body> <h1>TEMPLATE</h1>
       <div class="container">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

While testing I get this error:

```
expected token 'end of statement block', got '='
```

Edit: I missed including the variable in the header in template.html. Which I now know, to be the source of the error. Is there anyway to pass a variable to template.html, or is that not good practice?

Help!

Comment: One issue maybe the extra left brace here`{{% block content %}`. Although when I tested that syntax error on one of my templates I got a different error.

Comment: @Gohn67. Edited the template.html - i had missed the variable being passed. I guess its a different question now :( - how would I pass data into a template.html file thats being extended? This pertains to using a bootstrap navbar and making certain elements 'active'.

Comment: I think there is a syntax error here: `{% if pageType = 'home' %}`, should be `==`?

Comment: For the `pageType` variable, it should appear in your template.html so long as you pass it to the render_template function

Comment: @Gohn67 can you post {% if pageType = 'home' %}, should be == as an answer? I'll mark it correct.

That is the problem. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pageType` variable should appear in your template.html so long as you pass it to the `render_template` function. In your case, you have a syntax error here:

```
{% if pageType = 'home' %}
```

You need to use `==` instead, so it should look like this:

```
{% if pageType == 'home' %}
```